# Can Search API filter "Index full entity" be used in Search API views?

Tags: search, views

I have set up a Solr index for user profiles on my site with the [Search API Solr Search](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api_solr).  The profiles are pretty complicated-- several relations, lots of fields, and many theme templates to render them with complex logic.

I am trying to speed up the performance of my search views, and I found this option under **Data alterations** on the Solr index:

**Complete entity view**

*Adds an additional field containing the whole HTML content of the entity when viewed.*

I thought I could use this as a cache by saving the rendered HTML to Solr for the user profiles, and then, in my view, I could just display this one item, the complete entity view, instead of having to configure all my fields and views formatting templates.

So, I did the following:

1. At `/admin/config/search/search_api/index/MYSEARCH/fields`, I selected the field for indexing (complete entity view) as **fulltext**.
2. At `/admin/config/search/search_api/server/MYINDEX/edit`, I turned on "Retrieve result data from Solr" as noted in [this D.O post](https://www.drupal.org/node/1372744).

When I do this, I can now select the "Complete entity view" under **Fields** in the Views UI, but no result (no HTML output) is returned in the display.  How can I add the output of the "Complete entity view" in Views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be possible. I did the same thing with Search API + Elastic search (No Views module though). And yes it did speed up the results. However, in retrospect I may have been better of using Render Cache module in conjunction with an object cache like Redis and or Memcache.

The main pain point that I ran into doing full storage of HTML in the search server was that nearly every theming/template change required rebuilding the search index.

All that being said, if you want to keep going down this route I suggest using Solr's built in inspection tools to first validate that the user profile HTML has made it into Solr at all.

Comment: In my case, there are basically no theme changes, so it's fine if I have to rebuild the index every time.

Answer (score 0):

I had to clear the Drupal cache several times, but after doing so, I was able to index items as described in my original question.